# FadeTo() bei scrollTop

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, fadeto

```
<script>      
    $(window).scroll(function(){
        var fromTopPx = 717; // distance to trigger
        var scrolledFromtop = $(window).scrollTop();
        if(scrolledFromtop > fromTopPx){
            $("#farbe").fadeTo("slow", 0 );
        }else{
            $("#farbe").fadeTo("slow", 1 );

        }
    });

</script>
```

Hi, I have a fixed `div` that should not be displayed by default. If you go down 717px from the top, it should fade in. If you go back to the top, it should fade out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: well I can find that your code works fine, just test it changing 717 to 71, may be your page doesnt have the content to scroll

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this function, it's a lot cleaner.

```
$(window).bind("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 717) {
        $("#farbe").fadeIn();
    } else {
        $("#farbe").stop().fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Dont forget to add the CSS: `#farbe{display: none;}` so it's hidden by default.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ZHkY8/)

Comment: Difference with OP's code? EDIT: sorry, just saw the `bind()` didn't saw the cleaner part

Comment: @A.Wolff i think it's the CSS display none.

Comment: It's a cleaner and easier method, The code is different yes. But it works the same if I understood right.

Comment: @user3406182 How does it fix your issue??? BTW, here it is doing the opposite of what you seem to looking for

Comment: It actually is the opposite. But as the OP said "Hi, I have a fixed div that should not be displayed by default. If you go down 717px from the top, it should fade in. If you go back to the top, it should fade out."

Comment: @KeesSonnema all my apologizes, i just saw it +1